# How to type Eastern Arabic numerals and Arabic letters in the same Excel cell in Windows?

Tags: excel, vba, windows, arabic-support

I have an *Excel VBA* project that needs to run on both Mac OS and Windows 10. The program needs users to type in Eastern Arabic numerals and Arabic letters into the same cell. As my animated gif demonstrates (click for detail), I know how to do this on Mac OS (shown at top), but I can't figure out how to do it in Windows 10 (shown at bottom).

[image]

Notice that I switch between languages using the menubar/taskbar, and in each case it works fine for letters. The problem is that Windows Excel won't let me type the Eastern Arabic numerals into a cell as I do on Mac OS.

**In other words, I want what happens in cell B4 on the Mac (top) to happen in cell C4 on Windows (bottom).**

Please note:

1) I need users to ***actually type*** the Eastern Arabic numerals into a cell

2) I have the language pack for Arabic installed on Windows 10

3) Because the terminology can be confusing, here is a [helpful table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals):

[image]

**Update:** Here is the animated gif showing it working after applying the solution of mahmoud elgebaly

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on windows operating sys change the region and language settings in control panel to arabic
then
go to excel ribbon 
tab (home)
group (alignment)
select  (right-to-left direction)

Comment: I confirm that this answer works and have added a new animated gif at the bottom of my original post to demonstrate. 

In Windows 10, I went to Settings --> Time & Language --> Region --> Regional format --> Arabic (Egypt).

I then opened Excel, switched from English to Arabic in the taskbar (EN --> AR), typed 'abc 123' into a cell I got what is shown in the animated gif (شلاؤ ١٢٣). If you look carefully you can see that in Windows the '123' typed into the cell is converted to Eastern Arabic only after hitting the return key, while with Mac it's always 'what you see is what you get'